# Programmatically create posts and add featured images while skip uploading to media library

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media-library

Let's say I use this code to programmatically create a bunch of WordPress posts based on the values from the database. The database table I query, has one column that stores urls of images that are located in a folder in the server. I want to add those images as featured images when the posts are created.

- Is there a way how to simultaneously create posts and add a featured image to them 
  using the script I have created below?
- And is it possible to skip uploading those featured images to media library? - (since
  they are constantly being imported and deleted)

```
foreach ( $rows as $db ) {
$pictures  = explode(",", $db->pictures); // get images from the database

$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => $post_title,
'post_content' => $content,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_input'    => array(
               'property_features' => $features     
                 ),
    'meta_input' => array(
    'energy' =>$energy,
    'property_price' => $prices)
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
}
```